# Listen to any changes in a cursor in android

Tags: android, database, android-cursor

I would like to listen to any changes in a cursor. Is it possible to achieve this without using a contentprovider in android?

Note:(I am not using any data adapter)

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `registerContentObserver()` or `registerDataSetObserver()`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that You don't need to use content Provider.When ever the data changes(like during insertions,deletions etc..) you can just call getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri uri, ContentObserver observer) and set a contentObserver in your activity to listen for the change.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if your changes in the cursor are due to requery() or some other method on the cursor like close(), then you can use a dataset observer to track the changes.

But you will need a content provider, if you want to be updated automatically when something changes in your data source, eg your sqlite database.

Comment: what do you mean by "which cursor"?

Comment: is it a merge cursor, sqlitecursor or just a plain cursor?