# ContentResolver.insert() not reflected immediately?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

The following code snippet from my activity's `onCreate()` works great (i.e. `cursor.moveToFirst()` is **true**) in subsequent invocations of my application:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MyProvider.Notes.TITLE, "title");
values.put(MyProvider.Notes.NOTE, "note");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Uri newlyInsertedRecord = cr.insert(notesUri, values);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int id = cursor.getInt(0);
    String ttl = cursor.getString(1);
    String nte = cursor.getString(2);
    Log.i(TAG, id + ", "+ ttl + ", "+ nte);
}
else
    Log.e(TAG, "Why isn't the insert reflected immediately?");
```

So, I *know* for certain that the `cr.insert()` is executed properly.

But on **first** invocation of my application, `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns **false**, despite the `cr.insert()` preceding it.

Why?

Do I need some sort of a "flush" or "close" statement?

Comment: how are you creating the cursor?

Comment: @Pork Yes, but *before* the `insert()`. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to acquire a new cursor after doing the insert, as the cursor in itself doesn't listen for changes in the db.

Or write a [Content Observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) and [inform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680916/listen-to-any-changes-in-a-cursor-in-android) it of the changes.